# The theme is broken when I enable the "Optimize CSS files" option

Tags: 7, theming

The theme I made is broken, when I enable the "Optimize CSS files" option. I have cleared the cache, but the theme still doesn't work. With Firefox and Internet Explorer it is OK, but with Google Chrome is not OK at all.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have that in all my CSS files, and it works fine in Chrome.

try:

- converting the CSS file to UTF-8 (if it's not)
- removing any multiline comments

/* 
This is a

multi-line comment. 
*/

Comment: Did you enable the optimized CSS files too?

Comment: always, once the site is launched

Comment: your ways works like a charm. i have multiline comments in my style css file, when i delete, it's ok under chrome when enable the optimized CSS files  .